# Node-ipc: How to send to socket by ID

Tags: node.js, ipc

I have a Node-ipc server running and the server can receive a socket and then respond to the client that sent the original message. I need to send a message to a different socket other than the sending socket. Is this possible and how would it be done?

I tried using the clients ID but this did not work. Se

```
ipc.server.on('server.connected', (message, socket) => {
    console.log('NEW PROCESS CONNECTED: ' + message)
    ipc.server.emit(socket, 'new.command', {
        data: 'This is the new command'
    })
})
```